# How to determine if these are true, false, or unknown?

Tags: logic

How would I resolve these statements? Can someone please show me the steps for a few of them?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to philosophySE. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A, B, and D are true and C is unknown, to resolve the statement `(DvC)&(Av~B)` you'll want to plug in the truth values for the corresponding symbols and evaluate the expressions.

- `(DvC)&(Av~B)` can be read as *(D or C) and (A or not-B).*

...replacing the truth values leaves us with:

- (true or unknown) and (true or not true).

Given the [principles of non-contradiction and the excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought#The_three_traditional_laws), I am going to presume that "not true" is rendered into "false" instead of "unknown" - because we do *know something* about the truth value of "~B" inasmuch as we know that B is true and ~B is not true, hence we can positively say ~B is false instead of negatively resolving that though "not B" is "not true", what "~B" evaluates to is unknown. So, we have:

- (true or unknown) and (true or false)

Next, you'll want to evaluate the or statements into a truth value before comparing the conjunction (the "and" expression). Here I am also going to presume that you are using [an inclusive or and not an exclusive or](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3246264/5225057), and we can use the following truth table to evaluate the possible results of the two "inclusive or" statements (the column under "a V b" is the inclusive or, and, the column under "a V̲ b" is exclusive or):

[image]

Given an inclusive or, you can see that if at least one of the two values is true, then the entire expressions evaluates to true. So for (DvC) (i.e. "true inclusive or unknown") we end up with true. Likewise for (Av~B) (i.e. true inclusive or false) we end up with true. Now the statement can be analyzed according to the conjunction:

- true and true

As we can see from working out the truth table for the conjunction of two terms (note that this image uses the ∧ notation for conjunction instead of the ampersand &):

[image]

...(DvC)&(Av~B) is analyzed as "true and true" which evaluates to "true."

[Q.E.D.](http://www.mathopenref.com/qed.html)

---

PhilosophySE isn't here to do your homework for you, but to resolve the remaining expressions and presuming the ⊃ symbol is used for "If ..., then ..." conditionals, this might help:
[image]

Lastly, I am assuming that the equals sign "=" is being used such that "T=F" and "F=T" are both false, and, "T=T" and "F=F" are both true. Also, I'm presuming the tilda "~" is being used for "not" such that ~T is false, ~F is true, ~~T is true and ~~F is false.

Comment: For 1 and 2 I got false, for 3 I got unknown, and 4 I got true. Do you mind checking if my answers are correct?

Comment: @user25705 Did you re-evaluate your answers to questions 1 through 4?